# Jquery-UI Hide and Show problem with the direccion of the slide

Tags: jquery, html, function, jquery-ui, show-hide

I have a problem with my code, I am trying to make a dynamic screen with 4 buttons, the problem is the following and I find it quite strange, since, when I press the buttons in one direction (
the order of the first, then the second, then the third and fourth), the show method does not work correctly with the animation of show, but instead, when I press the buttons in descending order of the buttons, in the opposite direction of button, the function show works correctly, I could not replicate the example in fiddleJS, but this is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#idConstruccion").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#idDivTransformacion').hide("slide", {direction: "up"}, 500);
    $('#idDivReparacion').hide("slide", {direction: "down"}, 500);
    $('#idDivDemolicion').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);

    $('#idDivConstrucion').show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

    fnscroll()
})

$("#idTransformacion").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#idDivConstrucion').hide("slide", {direction: "up"}, 500);
    $('#idDivReparacion').hide("slide", {direction: "down"}, 500);
    $('#idDivDemolicion').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);

    $('#idDivTransformacion').show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

    fnscroll()
})

$("#idReparacion").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#idDivConstrucion').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
    $('#idDivTransformacion').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
    $('#idDivDemolicion').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);

    $('#idDivReparacion').show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

    fnscroll()
})

$("#idDemolicion").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#idDivConstrucion').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
    $('#idDivTransformacion').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
    $('#idDivReparacion').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);

    $('#idDivDemolicion').show("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

    fnscroll()
})

function fnscroll(){

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#scroll_point').offset().top}, 200, function() {
        $('#scroll_point').focus();
        $('#scroll_point').blur()
    })
}

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kraden95/zsb5890w/5/

Video Example of the web page; https://youtu.be/bvWtqhMVVB0

Beforehand thank you very much!

Comment: I checked your fiddle and your youtube video and honestly I don't understand the problem... they both look like they work fine. What is the expected result and how does it differ from what you are seeing?